# Installing 2 copies of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I am currently running a dual boot system with Ubuntu 12.04(64 bit) and Windows7.

I am trying to install a toolkit which has conflict with some opencv libraries. I tried cleaning up my libraries and some fixes but none of them work.

I want test this toolkit on a fresh Ubuntu install. Can I make another fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, without affecting the current installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the other Ubuntu for testing, then creating a virtual machine in VirtualBox is the easiest option.

Alternatively, if you only need a one-off Ubuntu instance then just booting from an Ubuntu LiveUSB may be enough.

I wouldn't resize partitions and install another Ubuntu just for testing, although you can do that too - you can have as many instances of Ubuntu (or different Linux distros) installed each in its own partition as you like.